# Copy command unable to copy Date into Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to insert rows like:

```
2016/02/03,name,12345,34,...
```

I am trying to copy a S3 file like so

```
copy events
from 's3://dailyevents/eventdata/l/'' 
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<access-key-id>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret-access-key>'
CSV 
DATEFORMAT AS 'YYYY/MM/DD';
```

However I am getting a type mismatch error as its interpreting 2016/02/03 as 3 separate values.

```
Invalid digit, Value 'n', Pos 3, Type: Integer
```

How can I get it to parse the first column as the date format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The copy command needs the column list as well for it to parse the the column as a date.

```
copy events
(event_date, event_name,event_id,cost)
from 's3://dailyevents/eventdata/l/'' 
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<access-key-id>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret-access-key>'
CSV 
DATEFORMAT AS 'YYYY/MM/DD';
```

Worked.

Comment: Ah! It seems that the column name tells it what type of field to expect, and therefore it knows when to parse the string as a date. Good work!